# Displaying collection data with key in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, associative-array

I have made Collection with keys but I am unable to retrieve this information. This is my code:

```
Dim test As Collection = New Collection
test.Add("This is a test", "testkey")
MsgBox(test("testkey").ToString)
```

I'm getting an error on last line:

> Argument 'Index' is not a valid value.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to store key/value pairs use, [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx). Here is how you can do it.

```
Dim dictionary As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
dictionary.Add("testkey", "This is a test")
MsgBox(dictionary("testkey"))
```